# Flatten Array object in javascript if child array have dynamic key value pair object

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I get flat array object of this array? I want to move all keys value from child array object to its parent object:

```
[
  {
    "Attributes": [
      {
        "Name": "profile",
        "Value": "UI"
      },
      {
        "Name": "phone_number",
        "Value": "+91123456789"
      },
      {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "to_test@test.in"
      }
    ],
    "UserCreateDate": 1524465619.163,
    "Username": "neeraj"
  }
]
```

Required JSON:

```
[
  {
    "UserCreateDate": 1524465619.163,
    "Username": "neeraj",
    "profile": "UI",
    "phone_number": "+91123456789",
    "email": "to_test@test.in"
  }
]
```

Comment: please share how the expected output will look like

Comment: i want like this:
Nested Json: [{
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Name": "email",
          "Value": "to@to.com"
        },{
          "Name": "username",
          "Value": "Jack"
        }
      ],
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserCreateDate": 1524491609.287
    }]
Required JSON:
 [{
      "email": "to@to.com",
"username" : "Jack",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserCreateDate": 1524491609.287,
      "UserLastModifiedDate": 1524492105.53,
      "UserStatus": "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD",
      "Username": "sachhida"
    }]

Comment: You completely changed the question after people did this work and submitted answers. I'm just deleting mine. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to iterate through your array and then use `array#map` to iterate through `Attributes` and using `Object.assign` create an object with all keys and `Attributes` objects in key-value format and return this object.

```js
const data = [ { "Attributes": [ { "Name": "profile", "Value": "UI" }, { "Name": "phone_number", "Value": "+91123456789" }, { "Name": "email", "Value": "to_test@test.in" } ], "UserCreateDate": 1524465619.163, "Username": "neeraj" } ],
      result = data.map(({Attributes, UserCreateDate, Username}) => Object.assign({UserCreateDate, Username}, ...Attributes.map(({Name, Value}) => ({[Name] : Value}))));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten using a recursive function that iterates over the keys/values of objects:

```js
const input = {
  "PaginationToken": "string",
  "Users": [{
    "Attributes": [{
      "Name": "string",
      "Value": "string"
    }],
    "Enabled": 'boolean',
    "MFAOptions": [{
      "AttributeName": "string",
      "DeliveryMedium": "string"
    }],
    "UserCreateDate": 'number',
    "UserLastModifiedDate": 'number',
    "Username": "string",
    "UserStatus": "string"
  }]
};
const getKeyValsFromObj = (obj) => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((accum, [key, value]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach(innerObj => accum = [...accum, ...getKeyValsFromObj(innerObj)]);
    } else accum.push([key, value]);
    return accum;
  }, []);
const keysVals = getKeyValsFromObj(input);
const finalObj = keysVals.reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
  obj[key] = val;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: **Sample Json**
 current json = [ { "Attributes": [ { "Name": "profile", "Value": "UI" }, { "Name": "phone_number", "Value": "+91123456789" }, { "Name": "email", "Value": "to_test@test.in" } ], "UserCreateDate": 1524465619.163, "Username": "neeraj" } ]

Required JSON: [ { "UserCreateDate": 1524465619.163, "Username": "neeraj", "profile": "UI", "phone_number":"+91123456789", "email":"to_test@test.in" } ]